# How to hide a parent by searching for content within a child using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide the parent of something I'm using find to check the content of. Can I refer to the following as "this"?

```
jQuery('.input-box').find('#preferred-shipping .ps-text').text().trim()
```

and then use it like so?

```
if(jQuery('.input-box').find('#preferred-shipping .ps-text').text().trim()==='You have backordered items in your cart, please choose a shipping status.') {
    jQuery(this).closest('.input-box').hide();
    jQuery(this).parent().hide();
}
```

Here's the JS Fiddle I created to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/Realto619/qrfytqu9/

Comment: No. `this` is not magic. Put whatever value you need to reuse in a variable.

Comment: I hope though that there is only one input box on the page, as otherwise the selector suggests you have duplicate ids on the page.

Comment: @Ryan I thought about doing that earlier, but when I tried it I didn't have any luck either: https://jsfiddle.net/Realto619/r3q5vuLw/2/

Comment: @Taplar Good point. I added that just to make sure that it didn't hide both instances of  .input-box  and should have changed the id for the second one. I updated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Realto619/qrfytqu9/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.input-box').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('#preferred-shipping .ps-text').text().trim()==='You have backordered items in your cart, please choose a shipping status.';
}).hide();
```

If the filter doesn't match anything, the hide will be skipped.

Comment: I updated that JSFiddle but it doesn't seem to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/Realto619/qrfytqu9/2/

Comment: @user3561924 that fiddle isn't including jQuery.  Open up your console and look at the errors.  And that fiddle has duplicate 'preferred-shipping' ids.

Comment: D'oh! The jQuery include wasn't working because I didn't use HTTPS, so after i fixed that it worked like a charm! https://jsfiddle.net/Realto619/qrfytqu9/7/

Comment: Oooooh, dude you're making it hard on yourself.  :).  On the javascript section, if you click the part on the top left of the box that says javascript, it will open a menu so you can load jQuery versions provided by jsfiddle automatically.